# How to create a class common to AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, oop

I am attempting to create a menu bar that lives in all of my activities. To do this, I've extended `AppCompatActivity` in `AppMenu.java` file. The idea here is to call my custom `AppMenu.getMenu(...)` method in every activity.

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to call `getMenu` in my activities.

**AppMenu.java**:

```
public class AppMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void getMenu(BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView, int selected) {

        // Set Home selected
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(selected);

        // Perform item selected listener
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch(item.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.messages:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dm.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.home:
                        return true;
                    case R.id.profile:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), userProfile.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // How can I call getMenu?
        AppMenu m = new AppMenu(); // Can not resolve this
        getMenu(); // Can not resolve this either
    }
}
```

For additional context, I am following [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-implement-bottom-navigation-with-activities-in-android/) GeeksForGeeks article but I do not think it's a great idea to repeat the same menu code in every activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is instead of extend AppCompatActivity, extend your AppMenu (I would say this should be called BaseMenuActivity), it would be like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppMenu {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getMenu()
}
```

}